# Pulling Prior Year Month to date data

Tags: sql

I'm completely new at SQL and I'm struggling with this query. Hope the following is clear.

I have to pull data from a server using Excel sql import.

The table has a column with dates, the header column is named: `rept_date`

This will be a daily report and I need to extract the following data daily: **Prior Year, MTD data, up to yesterday**:

If today is `2016-08-17` then I need the data between

- `2015-08-01` (current month start -1 year)
- and `2015-08-16` (yesterday -1 year)

I tried this query but it doesn't work because it gives me back all 2015-08 data (until the 31st) which i don't want:

```
Select * from "name of the table" 
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,rept_date) = DATEPART(yyyy,dateadd(yy,-1,GETDATE())) 
AND DATEPART(m,rept_date) = DATEPART(m,GETDATE())
```

Can anyone help? fixing this or any completely different query?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please share sample table data and desired output.. Helps in visualizing the problem and thereby provide a solution.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS, looks like SQL Server.

Comment: `I tried this query but it doesn't work because it gives me back all 2015-08 data (until the 31st) which i don't want:` Research _grouping_ and _aggregation_.

Comment: @underscore_d Read carefully - OP needs to study date functions and not aggregation. There is no aggregation here, OP wants all rows.

Comment: @ppeterka Oh, I see the "daily" now, so I guess it's more of a cumulative result that's wanted? But there's the key word: "guess". If the OP has asked the question clearly, with sample input and output data, there would be no potential for misinterpretation. As written, it doesn't seem like a very clear or useful question.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server syntax is a bit strange for calculating first of month, etc.:

```
WHERE -- first of LYM
   rept_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()) - 12, '19000101')
  AND -- start of the same day LY
   rept_date < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())))
```

There's a nice cheat sheet at [sqlmag.com](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/cheat-sheet-calculating-important-dates)

Comment: Wow, does it really not have a simple `datevalue(y, m, d)` function?

Comment: @underscore_d: There's a `DATEFROMPARTS` since SQL Server 2012, but the OP didn't tag the version he's using and it's not really much shorter when you have to use all those `DATEPART(day|month|year, GETDATE())`

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have 2012/2014 servers available but due to an un-upgraded server hosting most of my reporting demands and, erm, questionable application quality... have mostly worked on 2008 R2 so far, so I have to learn the newer features as I go. I'm glad 2012 has added that. Can't wait to get up to 2016, just for `STRING_SPLIT`... And yes, it's not like the OP even told us they were using SQL Server _at all_, although some variant is of course implied by its linking up with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean this up a little.  I formatted it like this so you can see the logic.  Hope it helps.

```
SELECT * FROM [YourTable]
WHERE CreationDate 
    BETWEEN 
        DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()-(DATEPART(d, GETDATE()- 1))) 
    AND 
        DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE() - 1)
```

Comment: Yor result includes the time portion instead of 00:00:00` :-)

Comment: Ha!  Yeah, you are right.  Guess I should have actually run it.  Well, other than that--- hehehe...